# How to get the row in join even though there is no matching data?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following two tables, Userdata and Activity:

Table Userdata

```
User           Email                                 RealName
Alpha          alpha@domain.com              Taylor
           
Beta          beta@domain.com              Samuelson
```

Table Activity

```
User           Group                                 MemberID
Alpha          5                                            09856
           
Gamma             2                                              09537
```

Now I tried to use the following sql statement:

```
SELECT Activity.*,Userdata.* FROM Activity INNER JOIN Userdata ON Userdata.User=Activity.User
```

However, the row for user Gamma has not been returned. How can I make him also returned even though there is no data for Gamma in Userdata?

Comment: Read up on inner join vs left join (vs cross join and other join types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` joins the two tables only on rows for which values exist in both tables.  `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will accomplish what you want, allowing the joined table to have an empty set for any given value in the joined field which is otherwise present on the initial table:

```
SELECT
    Activity.*,
    Userdata.*
FROM
    Activity
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Userdata ON Userdata.User = Activity.User
```

You can also refer to [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for additional information about `JOINs`.